# python regex add space between digits and a given character

Tags: python, regex

I was looking for the solution, but no success. I am really bad at REGEX. I am trying to add a space between a digit and a character.

```
text = "Split XXTX99V 23...490V -23V 34-499V".
```

Expected output: `Split XXTX99V 23...490 V -23 V 34-499 V`.

My code:

```
pattern = r'(?<=\d)V(?=[\s,-]|$)'
re.sub(pattern,' V', text, flags=re.I)
output: 
"Split XXTX99 V 23...490 V -23 V 34-499 V"
```

How to except "XXTX99V" to adding space?

Comment: Why shouldn't the `XXTX99V` get a space? Its `v` follows a digit. What's the logic you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match and capture `<letter><digits>V` into Group 1 and just match your pattern using an alternation, and then analyze the match data object in the lambda passed as the replacement argument and replace accordingly.

The regex will look like

```
([A-Za-z]\d+V)|(?<=\d)V(?=[\s,-]|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zPS9WV/1). It is basically `([A-Za-z]\d+V)|YOUR_REGEX` where `(...)` is `x.group(1)` value in the lambda. See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/MiwcYV):

```py
import re
text = 'Split XXTX99V 23...490V -23V 34-499V'
pattern = r'([A-Za-z]\d+V)|(?<=\d)V(?=[\s,-]|$)'
print(re.sub(pattern, lambda x: x.group(1) or ' V', text, flags=re.I))
# => Split XXTX99V 23...490 V -23 V 34-499 V
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time! It works as I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the regex [pypi module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) to get the position before the V only when preceded by digits starting with a word boundary.

In the replacement use a space.

```
(?<=\b\d+)(?=V(?:[\s,-]|$))
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\b\d+)` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is a word boundary followed by 1+ digits
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `V` Match literally
  - `(?:[\s,-]|$)` Match either one of the listed characters or and or sttring
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PazTLE/1) and a [Python demo using the regex module](https://tio.run/##LY3RCsIgFEDf/YqLBFNyEnMvRmMfUYiQPTSSEmoTd4MF/btZ9Ho4hxNfeJtGlXN4xCkhJH/1CyHoF4QO6D7eA4K1B6u1gUZJKVu9MVA3yoBq67ZgSuIZ0aexBImyfte5wV3WnPWdYf326GZRn94rzouYwojs95Dzc2D/UEAFlYDvlPOcPw)

```
import regex

text = "Split XXTX99V 23...490V -23V 34-499V"
pattern = r"(?<=\b\d+)(?=V(?:[\s,-]|$))"
print(regex.sub(pattern, ' ', text))
```

Output

```
Split XXTX99V 23...490 V -23 V 34-499 V
```

Comment: I have chosen another answer as it is more flexible. In fact, the character 'V' is a variable and with your code, I got the following: error: nothing for fuzzy constraint at position 13. I did not post the full problem, sorry. And thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: @grozich No problem at all, glad you found a solution to your problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
text = "Split XXTX99V 23...490V -23V 34-499V"
```

You can do:

```
>>> re.sub(r'([ ]|^)([\d.-]+)(V)(?=[\s-]|$)', r'\1\2 \3', text)
Split XXTX99V 23...490 V -23 V 34-499 V
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I have chosen another amswer as it was for flexible to my problem.